# Is a certain Look and Feel guaranteed to be available?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

From what I've found out, the Nimbus Look and Feel was introduced in Java 6 Update 10.

I have project where I use that Look and Feel.

Is there any situation where, the user has a Java VM newer than 6 update 10 (for example 6 update 26) and the Nimbus Look and Feel is not available ? This situation might occur if for example, Look and Feels can be manually/explicitly removed, but I've not been able to find out if this can be done.

So basically, is there a 100 % guarantee that, if the user has the proper Java VM version, the Nimbus Look and Feel will be available 100 % of the time ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *clear* way for a user to remove a particular Look & Feel from their JVM.  Anything is possible, though.

What's wrong with just checking for it in the code?

Comment: Well, a particular problem is with JTextFields. In Nimbus their height is a lot smaller and, if Nimbus is applied, I must make them bigger.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect and react to Nimbus being installed?

Comment: No, I know how to do that. I'm asking if I need to. If there is no way a user can remove Look and Feel's from the JVM, then I don't need to. But if he can...

Answer (score 4):

In Java 7 the package path is changed ("sun" removed: `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`): `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`, so it depends how you invoke the look and feel. In general this action of oracle might be seen as a positive endorsement of the nimbus look and feel.

Comment: Note that they didn't remove the old name. They retained the class `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` as an empty extension of `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`, so code which uses the Java 6 class name still works fine.